# Facebook jQuery Plugins

Tags: facebook, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

What are the most Facebook like jQuery plug-ins, I would love to have a solid list of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a list of 23 of them:

http://www.jquery.wisdomplug.com/jquery-plugins/facebook-jquery-plugins/23-best-jquery-facebook-style-plugins/